# php file getting recognized but not giving input

Tags: php, html, wamp, wampserver

I have a html and php in "C:\wamp64\www\module", html file is able to access php file but the php file is not outputting anything. It's blank, it's not even printing the code like it usually happens.
Following is the php code:

```
<html>
<body>

<?php
phpinfo();
?>

</body>
</html>
```

When I execute "file:///C:/wamp64/www/module/html.html" this file, "file:///C:/wamp64/www/module/phpworking.php" this is the address I get and the page is totally blank.

WHAT IS THE PROBLEM???

Comment: PHP scripts run server-side. The browser can't execute them. What you're doing is directly opening the PHP file in your browser. You need to launch the server, then connect to something like `localhost:8080/phpworking.php`, `localhost:80/phpworking.php` etc. depending on your configuration.

Answer (score 1):

If you have already enabled your wamp server, you need to access your files through your browser via **http://localhost/name_of_your_file.php**